# Why is mbedTLS ECDSA signature dependend on hashing algorithm?

Tags: hash, cryptography, digital-signature, mbed, polarssl

I am currently working on signing a hashed message using mbedTLS (formerly polarSSL) library. I am currently stuck with using the obvious function:

```
int mbedtls_ecdsa_write_signature( mbedtls_ecdsa_context *ctx, mbedtls_md_type_t md_alg,
                       const unsigned char *hash, size_t hlen,
                       unsigned char *sig, size_t *slen,
                       int (*f_rng)(void *, unsigned char *, size_t),
                       void *p_rng )
```

It seems that this works properly but I have a problem with the given parameter `mbedtls_md_type_t md_alg`. This parameter identifies message digest algorithm that was used for the given hash.

`md_alg` is an enum defined in 'md.h' and describes the following values:

`enum   mbedtls_md_type_t { 
  MBEDTLS_MD_NONE =0, MBEDTLS_MD_MD2, MBEDTLS_MD_MD4, MBEDTLS_MD_MD5, 
  MBEDTLS_MD_SHA1, MBEDTLS_MD_SHA224, MBEDTLS_MD_SHA256, MBEDTLS_MD_SHA384, 
  MBEDTLS_MD_SHA512, MBEDTLS_MD_RIPEMD160 
}`

As I need to be using SHA3 (keccak 256) as a hashing algorithm, mbedTLS does not offer this. I am now hashing using another method and put in the SHA3 hash into the `mbedtls_ecdsa_write_signature()` function.

As `md_alg` parameter I have tried out the different values that define the message digest algorithm and I get the following output:

`(md_alg)  + Signature:  (len: length)
  signature`

`(3)  + Signature:  (len: 70) 304402206AD43BB99B8D97A0890ED7295BDDF8E826AF44AA1FAC9B471EBD415078F3194C02204C0DE87286C2C2B6160B7410A7692DE0995FE79347752A1E828E829FFD981257
(4)  + Signature:  (len: 72) 3046022100D8C89CD146F08ECA0ACCD66AD0FAF07D8ED761602EBB5DAC8E4F2B6E9634EBC4022100897583BAE04B0B46044AD5910CC704039F7B46DDCBA46344E065687798B2E605
(5)  + Signature:  (len: 71) 3045022100EBDFC64BC39F77753E5255AED340CFB8946584B7D2AAF5F32A611BFF29631CFC02201233084DD8E96598483F2BEAFACD03E5D8449511A3F6BAB85175158950333084
(6)  + Signature:  (len: 71) 304502200E7220C8697456CA3151C967EEB2DB6AD6F9E6ACB740E7980D41582496635228022100A01FA55C71A30D042C5932498C0F69ADAB81F5026E5CC0204A304217883B814C
(7)  + Signature:  (len: 71) 3045022100ADBC91C37D20EA747B9854C26CFE067311C86A168FE8B06237C1D0EB2F8E6F04022004B99EE9B920B57BAE1BFFCED6BDD7ED3C48571BC4D7326F67EC90AF045AC193
(8)  + Signature:  (len: 71) 3045022027CC7F76558EF628370E3554B575A0FD15F55952AB2E1CC30AC51A21DEFAE1AC0221009746FF2012E005057BFF0674E78235BD08B7C54C2547CAC63EDD5B160245A309
(9)  + Signature:  (len: 70) 3044022059512D16AC85EB8BFDFBD488A497A0CAA28AEA0A53F280FD7FDB4297C4D49DBD02200AAD2F32B63C76B82B75F3C97F555E5D895C3A8717D5E617AAFD7E8788E4311F`

As you can see, choosing different values for md_alg results in different signatures (given the same hash and private_key).

So far I have been looking through 'ecdsa.c' source file and can not find a reason for why choosing different values for `md_alg` results in different output signatures.

Is there anything I can do differently for using a SHA3 hash and why do the signature differ from one another?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Short answers:

- you don't need to do anything differently
- the signatures differ because the signature algorithm is randomised

This is because the purpose of the `mbedtls_md_type_t md_alg` passed to `mbedtls_ecdsa_write_signature` is not to indicate the algorithm that was used to create the given hash.

What happens is, that the algorithm constructs a pseudorandom generator (hmac-drbg) based on the given `md_alg` and seeds it with the private key. Now, if the hash algorithm is different, then the pseudorandom sequence will be different and that makes the signature itself different as well.